# Basic File IO in C Produces all a's

Tags: c

I am using CodeBlocks on Windows to compile.

Why the program gives me this answer? Why there are so much `a`s and don't get the answer `123456abcdef`?

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char s[100] = "abcdef";
    char c1 = '0';
    int i = 0;

    fp = fopen("ot.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("file open error");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        fputc(s[i], fp);
        i++;
        printf("%d", i);
    }

    while (c1 != EOF) {
        c1 = fgetc(fp);
        putchar(c1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: `c1` should be `int`. You also want to "rewind" the fie to the beginning after writing it. And what will happen to `putchar(c1);` if `c1` is `EOF`? Also your `fopen` mode is incorrect. You want either `"w+"` or `"r+"`

Comment: In addition to changing `c1` to type `int` (because it might not be possible to store the value `EOF` in a `char`), the final character written to standard output by `putchar(c1);` will be bogus when `c1` is `EOF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `c1` should be defined with type `int` to accommodate for all values returned by `fgetc()`. a `char` cannot unambiguously store `EOF`.
- You should open the file in write+update mode `"w+"`
- You should rewind the stream pointer before reading back from it for 2 reasons: a seek operation is required between read and write operations and you want to read the characters from the start of the file.
- You need to test for `EOF` **after** reading a byte with `fgetc()`, otherwise you will output the `EOF` converted to `unsigned char` to `stdout` before exiting the loop.
- It is good style to `return 0;` from `main()` to indicate success and non-zero to indicate failure.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    char s[] = "abcdef";
    int i, c;

    fp = fopen("ot.txt", "w+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("file open error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        fputc(s[i], fp);
        i++;
        printf("%d", i);
    }

    rewind(fp);
    while ((c1 = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```